# Dynamic query to show XY coordinates as values in columns (FGDB)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, file-geodatabase, feature-layer, attribute-rules

I have a point FC in a file geodatabase.

I want to create a feature layer on the FC that has columns that show the X & Y coordinates of the geometry.

The values in the query would be dynamic; they would change if the underlying data in the FC was edited.

> The result would be similar to what can be done with a query layer on
> an enterprise/st_geometry geodatabase table—but for a file
> geodatabase:
>
> ```
> select
>     p.*,
>     sde.st_x(p.shape) as x, 
>     sde.st_y(p.shape) as y
> from
>     points p
> ```
>
> *Yes, I'm aware that we can't use SQL to access the geometry of a FGDB FC. I'm just using this as an example to demonstrate the functionality that I'm looking for.*

Is it possible to do this for FGDB FCs in ArcGIS Desktop 10.7.1 or ArcGIS Pro (any version)?

Comment: You can submit an enhancement request at ideas.esri.com

Comment: A file geodatabase is not a database, they don't support extended queries, you'd have better luck with a personal geodatabase that is a database. Is there a reason that you're not adding the fields X and Y then populating by calculate geometry https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/tools/data-management-toolbox/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm and https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/calculate-geometry-attributes.htm for ArcGIS Pro?

Comment: running a python code with ArcPY Model you can do.

Answer (score 2):

Attribute rules were added in FGDBs in the last couple of versions (perhaps at 2.4).

Assuming you're on the right version you should be able to create an attribute rule that fires on every insert/edit to update your fields.

Comment: Thanks. Additionally, there is an answer on this page that provides step-by-step instructions for using attribute rules: [Calculating the X and Y coordinate automatically for the point layer](https://community.esri.com/ideas/4968-calculating-the-x-and-y-coordinate-automatically-for-the-point-layer#comment-79823)